# 管理画面からWordPress本体のアップデートが完了できない

Tags: php, wordpress

#### 概要

- WordPressの管理画面=>更新から本体の更新ができない（途中で管理画面がロックされる）
- WordPress本体は「WordPress 5.9」に更新しようとしている

#### 試したこと

- プラグインを全て停止させた状態での本体アップデート実行
- WordPressのディレクトリ、wp-content配下に存在する「upgrade」、「plugins」ディレクトリの権限を777や704にした状態かつプラグインを停止させた状態でのアップデート
- デバッグログを有効にする。wp-config.phpに次の記載を追加してアップデートを試しましたがwp-content配下にdebug.logは表示されませんでした。
  追加した記載=>define(‘WP_DEBUG_LOG’, true);
- ブラウザのキャッシュを削除した状態でのアップデート
- wp-config.phpのPHP実行時間の確認=>set_time_limit(600)と10分間で指定されていたので問題ないように思われます。

#### お聞きしたいこと

- 上記の「試したこと」を全て並行して行ってもWordPress本体をのアップデートは完了しませんでした(処理が途中で止まる)
- 他にWordPress本体がアップデートできない原因となり得るものがあれば教えて頂けませんでしょうか？よろしくお願い致します。

Comment: 今のwordpressのバージョンは何をお使いですか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。現在使用しているwordpressのバージョンは5.5.8です。